# Set data type in excel cells in PHP Excel class

Tags: php, phpexcel

Using PHP Excel class , how can I set percentage data type in Excel cells.

I tried with following code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2')
    ->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
        array( 
            'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
        )
    );
```

But in this case if I add value to 'I2' as '2.35', it displayed as '235.00%' in generated excel file.

Is there anyway to show it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is MS Excel behaviour:

Open MS Excel, set a cell value to 2.35, then set the cell number format to percentage (with or without decimals) and you'll see 235.00% as the formatted value.

PHPExcel simply reflects this.

If you want to display 2.35% in Excel, then you need the cell value as 0.0235 and then set the number format mask to percentage. Do the same in PHPExcel, and you'll get the result you want

Note that this does not change the cell value in any way, simply the way that it is displayed.

Alternatively, set the number format mask to:

```
#,##0.00"%"
```

Comment: You are correct. Although it looks strange at first, it actually works better when you use it in a formula (`100*2.35 = 235` and `100*235% = 235`)

Comment: It works with setting number mask to #,##0.00"%", thank you very much. Just afraid whether it would create any issues in cells calculations.

Comment: It has no affect whatsoever on cell calculations because the value in the cell is still 2.35: number format masking purely changes the "appearance" of the value, not the value itself